# How to define escape sequence and character literal using Irony?

Tags: c#, grammar, irony

I'm implementing a grammar that has some rules like this:

```
char-literal    ::= ' regular-char '  
    ∣    ' escape-sequence '  

escape-sequence ::= \ ( \ ∣  " ∣  ' ∣  n ∣  t ∣  b ∣  r ∣  space )  
    ∣    \ (0…9) (0…9) (0…9)  
    ∣    \x (0…9∣ A…F∣ a…f) (0…9∣ A…F∣ a…f)
```

The point is that, I don't know how to define character literal using Irony. Any idea?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Why don't you just do it?

Comment: I have no idea, how to define character literal in Irony. I see there is NumberLiteral, StringLiteral, but no CharLiteral. How can I do it in Irony?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look a Irony samples, they are included by default.

The C# Irony grammar has already an example:

`StringLiteral CharLiteral = TerminalFactory.CreateCSharpChar("CharLiteral");`

The implementation looks something like this:

`public static StringLiteral CreateCSharpChar(string name) {
      StringLiteral term = new StringLiteral(name, "'", StringOptions.IsChar);
      return term;
    }`